# How do you limit results from search per field type in SearchKick

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I have multiple stores and each store has many products. When a user searches for products, I want to limit the number of products returned per store to make sure one store does not dominate the search results.

How would I accomplish this in `searchkick`

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :products 
end 

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store 
end
```

I have tried but I get weird results

```
Product.search("red shoes", aggs: {store_id: {limit: 10}})
```

Comment: How do i get the `top_hits` n hits  per store?

Comment: which language are you using ?
I believe you should look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html